# Systemd units: [Install] vs. command: start (cloud-config)

Tags: systemd, coreos, cloud-config

I'm configuring systemd in a cloud-config file for CoreOS. If I understand this correctly, I have two ways of starting a unit at boot:

Alternative 1, use the `[Install]`-section (as described in digital oceans [guides](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files)):

```
- name: initialize_data
  content: |
    [Unit]
    Description=Run a command

    [Service]
    Type=oneshot
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/mkdir /foo

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Alternative 2, drop the `[Install]`-section and use [`command: start`](https://coreos.com/os/docs/1339.0.0/cloud-config.html#coreos):

```
- name: initialize_data
  command: start
  content: |
    [Unit]
    Description=Run a command

    [Service]
    Type=oneshot
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/mkdir /foo
```

Is there any drawbacks of starting the unit using `command: start`? I get that I can't control which unit it will start after, but anything else? Will it honour `[Unit]`-directives such as `Requires=` and `After=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears on CoreOS there's little difference. When systemd is used on other Linux distributions, the distinction is that `start` only starts up a service, it doesn't cause it to *start on boot*. That's what `enable` does, by processing the `[Install]` section of a systemd file.

However, the CoreOS docs say that the `cloud-config` commands are processed on every boot. So by specifying a service to `start`  through `cloud-config`, the service is essentially *enabled* as well.

CoreOS likely includes both options to give you the full flexibility of accessing both `systemd` features.